# What can I do in order to get Google to show my videos in their "Videos" tab?

Tags: google-search, video

My website is indexed and ranking well. I can see the posts with the videos in the "All" tab.

Sadly not a single one of my posts is visible in the "Videos" tab and 99% of the content is videos.

I’m using a video sitemap.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have tagged this post with video sitemap so I am assuming you have one functioning on your website? Have you also submitted this to Google Search Console? I would also recommend using schema mark up to aid your appearance in video results. [This Google Developer article](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/intro) covers video sitemaps and schema mark up in an overview and links out to the more in-depth details of the best practice for both.

Comment: Hi Kirsty, 

I am very very new to this thing. I think we are using schema, yet I am not sure. Is it possible that you take a look? I wasn't able to find a way to send a private message, but if you can take a look it will be awesome, if I need to pay up I will gladly do so as well.

Btw I am on wordpress. 

Best regards,